# How do I Get the Client User's Last Message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

How would you get the object for the a bot's last message? I tried doing something like:

```
if (message.content.split(' ')[0] === 'test') {
   message.channel.sendMessage('Test')
   console.log(client.user.lastMessage.content)
}
```

If I trigger the conditional, the console gives me an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined`

Comment: That error means that `client.user.lastMessage` is undefined. That means that it's possible that there was no lastMessage (because remember, the message technically could still be sending, as nodeJS is non-blocking), or maybe the lastMessage attribute is wrong

Comment: So node.js doesn't wait for a thread to finish before moving on to the next command? If so, I tried to use `setTimeout()` to wait 3 seconds before it logs the message in the console. Is there a way to detect when the message is actually sent before it continues execution?

Comment: callbacks. Does sendMessage(String) overload a callback parameter?

Comment: I mean I reccomend trying to just console.log(client.user), and seeing if there's a lastMessage param or getter

Comment: Ah. The `lastMessage` variable doesn't exist at all in the object. The `lastMessageID` is also `null`. Is there an alternative way to set the `client.user.lastMessage` object since it doesn't appear to be in `read-only` mode?

Comment: Can I see the code?

Comment: @AritroSaha what portion of the code are you looking for exactly?

Comment: "client.on" and after

Comment: That wouldn't fit in a comment, and I don't believe the rest of my code is interfering with this in any way.

Comment: I know this is a dumb question, but have you defined "client"?

Comment: Yes: `const client = new Discord.Client();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the value of `client.user.lastmessage` is `null` is because you are just starting the bot, and it hasn't sent any messages before you are running your `'test'` command.

To circumnavigate this, I'd check if it's null (in case it isn't) and in the off-chance that it *is*, use a [MessageCollector](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/MessageCollector) and wait for your message to be sent.

```js
    if (client.user.lastMessage == null) {
        // Set the collector for the same channel
        // Ensure the id is the same
        var myID = client.user.id;
        // Create collector and wait for 5 seconds (overkill but you never know with bad internet/lots of traffic)
        const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(msg.channel, m => m.author.id === myID, { time: 5000 });
        collector.on('collect', message => {
            console.log(message.content);
            collector.stop("Got my message");
        });
    } else {
        console.log(client.user.lastMessage.content);
    }
```

Exact code Block I tested with:

```js
    client.on('message', msg => {
        if (msg.content === '$ping') {
            msg.reply("Pong!")
            if (client.user.lastMessage == null) {
                const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(msg.channel, m => m.author.id === client.user.id, { time: 10000 });
                collector.on('collect', message => {
                    console.log(message.content);
                    collector.stop("Got my message");
                })
            } else {
                console.log(client.user.lastMessage.content);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I executed your code snippet after making the bot send a message, but it never outputs anything to the console.

Comment: @Meh this works for me? Look at my edit for the exact code block I tested it with

Comment: I updated the discord.js library and it looks like it worked. Apparently, the version I was using was from January 2017.

Answer (score 2):

You code snippet is obsolete now. From Discord.js v13 and thereafter the following properties have been removed (including lastMessage) because [they are not provided by Discord and are not reliable](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#guildmember)

- GuildMember#**lastMessage**
- GuildMember#lastMessageId
- GuildMember#lastMessageChannelId

You have to implement a custom solution to track this information manually.